# Codeigniter not working on IIS

Tags: codeigniter, iis

I am trying to run Codeigniter in IIS. I am able to get the welcome page but not able to load any controller.

What i understand is that, it is executing the index.php file but if we give any value after that in the URL the IIS is not responding.

For example

`<domain>/<folder>/index.php` - Works

But

`<domain>/<folder>/index.php/welcome` - Doesn't Works

What I assume is that in the second case is that instead of executing the index.php, the IIS is treating it as a folder and looking for script inside index.php/welcome folder.

Is there any way to make it work.

The server is running on IIS  4. (It is running on our client machine and we don't have option to upgrade it. )

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to use .htaccess file on iis?

Comment: Did you try to customize the base link?